# show tables in database by php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have create simple function to check if table exists in the database or not ..
I want fetch all table in the database and i use like

```
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM plus LIKE '%group%'";
    $do = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $table = array();


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($do)) {
        $table[] = $row ;

    }
        print_r($table);

}
```

the output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => group_1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => group_2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => group_3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => group_4 ) )
```

I want all table in one array to encode with Json , 
and use the array to check in_array by PHP ..

**==Edited==**

I'm getting JSON as

```
[["group_1"],["group_2"],["group_3"],["group_4"]]
```

But, I'm expecting

```
["group_1","group_2","group_3","group_4"]
```

Comment: If your problem was solved then you should mark answer accpeted and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_encode`, to get your resultset as `json`

```
 echo json_encode($table);
```

---

Since, you are getting sub-array with your `$table` array, you need to merge them into single array to get your expected output.

You could make changes to your loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($do)) {
    array_merge($table,$row);
}

echo json_encode($table);
```

or, to print array

```
var_dump($table);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland Oh yes.

Comment: i want once array ..
json is return more than array ..4 array

Comment: @dont_stop means?? post expected output and current output

Comment: the current code is Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => group_1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => group_2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => group_3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => group_4 ) )
 and json code [["group_1"],["group_2"],["group_3"],["group_4"]] is not a object !
the expected ..
array(table 1 , table 2 , table 3 ) or json object {table1,table 2, table }